# change page name on page list

Tags: posts, pages, translation

I'm looking for the way to changes terms on wordpress backoffice. exemple : pages name on list page.
[image]

I don't found the .PO or .MO on wp-content/language/ to make changes.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: That's probably tied to the language of the installation which you can change by going to the general settings page in the WP Admin panel.

Comment: I'm using  English (United states) but i dont find the files to change names of pages. I'm looking for to translate somes english terms on wordpress backoffice

Comment: Those are probably hard coded into WordPress core though so changing them is not advisable in. In order to change them, you'll need to change the language of the entire installation to whatever language you want to use.

Comment: To you have an idea when can i found the terms on the picture? I thinks edit.php but not sure

Comment: You **NEVER** want to edit WordPress core files. Everytime it updates your changes are wiped out and you have to make them again. But why do you want "Pages" changed to a different language yet leave the site itself in English?

Comment: Yes it's in english. but I don't want to call it PAGES

Comment: The label is on line 1370 of `/wp-includes/post.php` but you're going to have to write a plugin to do this otherwise your changes will be wiped out every time WordPress updates. You could also create a custom post type and have it behave like pages as well.

Comment: thanks. but i don't found the line on post.php  to change the name of PAGES any idea? for CPT the problem is the Permalink.   ex : if i create house CPT it's create permalink www.mysite.com/house/permalink .  I need something like www.mysite.com/permalink   and only pages give me that

Comment: Your CPT plugin can include a custom re-write rule using `add_rewrite_rule($regex, $redirect, $after)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change built in post type labels with the `post_type_labels_{$post_type}` filter:

```
function wpd_change_page_labels( $labels ) {
    $labels->menu_name  = 'Specials';
    $labels->name  = 'Specials';
    $labels->singular_name  = 'Special';
    return $labels;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_labels_page', 'wpd_change_page_labels' );
```

EDIT- Refer to [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) for a full list of labels, there are probably some others you'll want to add to this.

Comment: Thank you Milo! That's what i was looking for. But one question, does this override the language files? I mean, does it have a higher priority than `text-domains`?

Comment: Thanks Milo can we change also (Edit Page) by (Edit Special) for exemple?

Comment: @sampaii the key for that is `edit_item`. Check the link I added above to `register_post_type`, that has a full list of labels. Some may not apply to a hierarchical post type, but there are probably some others you will also want to add.

Comment: @JackJohansson You can see where it all happens in [`get_post_type_labels`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/). The defaults are built containing translated strings, then the filter just overwrites whatever values you supply. If you wanted your changes translatable, you'd have to pass your values through a translation function with your own text domain.

Comment: Hmm, such as using `__('Special','text-domain')` instead of `Special`?

Comment: @JackJohansson yes